# Adding custom component dynamically

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

I've been trying this for several hours now and I haven't gotten far...

I am trying to create a custom component that can be added through XML and via code.
Adding through XML was pretty easy and was done in a minute but when I started working on adding the component through code a lot of problems occured.

The error I currently get:

```
JS: [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: o.default is not a constructor"
```

Tried to add a constructor in the script tag like this:

```
constructor(icon,label,tap) {
    this.icon = icon;
    this.label = label;
    this.tap = tap;
  },
  data () {
     return {
        isActive: false
     };
  },
  props: {
    icon: String,
    height: Number,
    width: Number,
    label: String,

    // Should have argument
    tap: Function,
},
```

Tried adding the component like this:

```
this.array.forEach(element => {
    var newComponent = new Component(element.icon,element.label,element.tap);
    this.$refs.container.addChild(newComponent);
  });
```

**EDIT**
Import statement

```
import Component from "./Component.vue";
```

Adding component

```
components: {
  Component
},
```

XML version

```
<Component ref="customComponent" :tap="onTap" label="Custom Component" :icon="icon"/>
```

Comment: Probably error with export/import component file, can you add import export lines too ?

Comment: @MarekMaszay I am able to use the component in my template just not in my code

Comment: Yea still put more lines of codes

Comment: @MarekMaszay done thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Not sure but probably you have missing `export default Component;` at end of files or add exports from Component.vue file too

Answer (score 0):

Try change next line, which tries to find default export from that file

```
import Component from "./Component.vue";
```

to this, which exports specific class from file

```
import {Component} from "./Component.vue";
```

Or add line below `Component.vue` file, to set default export

```
export default Component;
```

Comment: Do you perhaps have a example of how you would approach the component.vue?
https://github.com/nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template/blob/master/template/src/components/HelloWorld.vue is a example of how my component looks like from the inside.